# link snowflake to python

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect snowflake to Python using my user snowflake credentials but its getting error while executing(I have cross checked my sf credential everything is perfect), Later i have tried to use my colleagues user credentials to connect its working(used the same code but changed the credentials) no error and snowflake is connecting to his account. can anyone help me where would be the problem[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx0Di.png)

Comment: Please include full tech info in your question

Comment: The screenshot shows you're not able to reach the Snowflake account URL. The URL **https://ys46926.us-east-2.snowflakecomputing.com** is not correct as I can't reach it either.

Comment: When you say "have cross-checked the SF credentials", do you imply that the user id is working from the UI? What is the URL being used in the UI? The current one provided in the error stack trace looks incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of URLs that can be used to access your Snowflake account. I recommend SNOWFLAKE_DEPLOYMENT_REGIONLESS

You can run this query on your account to find them:

```
-- account URLs
select t.value:type::varchar as type,
       t.value:host::varchar as host,
       t.value:port as port
from table(flatten(input => parse_json(system$whitelist()))) as t
where t.value:type::varchar like 'SNOWFLAKE%';
```

There are several factors that could be impacting whether or not you can connect, including network policies or firewalls.

You can use [SnowCD (Connectivity Diagnostic Tool)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html) to rule out there are any issues connecting to Snowflake from your machine.

If you can connect from your local machine, but are attempting to via python from a remote machine, the issue is very likely a network policy (snowflake defined firewall) has been set to restrict IP addresses that can connect to Snowflake by your Snowflake admin.

If SnowCD reports no errors and network policies are ruled out, reach out to Snowflake support for further investigation.

If for some reason hyphens are not supported in the URL, you can replace them with underscores.

- `organization_name-account_name` (for most URLs and other general
  purpose usage)
- `organization_name_account_name` (for scenarios/features where hyphens
  are not supported in URLs)
- `organization_name.account_name` (for SQL commands and operations)

Where:

- `organization_name` is the name of your Snowflake organization.
- `account_name` is the unique name of your account within your
  organization.